# Polynomials with rational coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, diophantine-equations

Long time ago there was a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/)
on whether a polynomial bijection $\mathbb Q^2\to\mathbb Q$ exists. Only one attempt
of answering it has been given, highly downvoted by the way. But this answer isn't obviously
unsuccessful, because the following problem (for case $n=2$) remains open.

**Problem.** Let $f$ be a polynomial with rational (or even integer!) coefficients
in $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Suppose there exist two distinct points
$\boldsymbol a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\boldsymbol b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ from $\mathbb R^n$
such that $f(\boldsymbol a)=f(\boldsymbol b)$. Does this imply the existence
of two points $\boldsymbol a'$ and $\boldsymbol b'$ from $\mathbb Q^n$ satisfying
$f(\boldsymbol a')=f(\boldsymbol b')$?

Even case $n=1$ seems to be non-obvious.

**EDIT.** Just because we have a very nice counter example (immediately
highly rated by the MO community) by Hailong Dao in case $n=1$ and because
for $n>1$ there are always points $\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b\in\mathbb R^n$
with the above property, the problem can be "simplified" as follows.

Is it true for a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Q[\boldsymbol x]$ in $n>1$ variables
that there exist two points $\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b\in\mathbb Q^n$ such
that $f(\boldsymbol a)=f(\boldsymbol b)$?

The existence of injective polynomials $\mathbb Q^2\to\mathbb Q$ is discussed
in B. Poonen's [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3961)
(and in comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/)).
What can be said for $n>2$?

**FURTHER EDIT.**
The expected answer to the problem is in negative. In other words, there exist injective polynomials
$\mathbb Q^n\to\mathbb Q$ for any $n$.

Thanks to the comments of [Harry Altman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5583/harry-altman) and
[Will Jagy](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3324/will-jagy), case $n>1$ is now fully
reduced to $n=2$. Namely, any injective polynomial $F(x_1,x_2)$ gives rise to the injective
polynomial $F(F(x_1,x_2),x_3)$, and so on; in the other direction, any $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in more
than 2 variables can be specialized to $F(x_1,x_2,0,\dots,0)$.

In spite of [Bjorn Poonen's verdict](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3961)
that case $n=2$ can be resolved by an appeal to
the Bombieri--Lang conjecture for $k$-rational points on surfaces of general type
(or even to the 4-variable version of the $abc$ conjecture), I remain with a hope
that this can be done by simpler means. My vague attempt (for which I search
in the literature) is to start with a homogeneous form $F(x,y)=ax^n+by^n$,
or any other homogeneous form of *odd* degree $n$, which has
the property that only finitely many *integers* are represented by $F(x,y)$ with
$x,y\in\mathbb Z$ relatively prime. In order to avoid this finite set of "unpleasant"
pairs $x,y$, one can replace them by other homogeneous forms $x=AX^m+BY^m$ and
$y=CX^m+DY^m$ (again, for $m$ odd and sufficiently large, say),
so that $x$ and $y$ escape the unpleasant values.
Then the newer homogeneous form $G(X,Y)=F(AX^m+BY^m,CX^m+DY^m)$ will give
the desired polynomial injection. So, can one suggest a homogeneous form $F(x,y)$
with the above property?

Comment: Well, it's clear that this won't work if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ from considering $x^n$ when $n$ is odd.  That also shows it won't work if you replace it with general $\mathbb{Q}_p$, either...

Comment: For any polynomial in two variables there exist distinct  $a,b$ so that $f(a)=f(b)$, so the condition you put on $f$ is always
fulfilled.

Comment: Oh yes, I know this from the cited above answer. But I don't see why no rational pair $a',b'$ with this property exists.

Comment: For n = 1: doesn't the continuity of the graph of f imply that the answer is "yes"? Because in this case the condition is equivalent to saying that for some c in R, the horizontal line (call it L) y = c cuts the graph of f in at least two points. But then this property (of cutting the graph of f in at least two points) will not be destroyed if either we move L a bit up or a bit down. So certainly we can ensure c to be rational.

Comment: @auniket: Please check the solution below ($n=1$).

Comment: I see - that was pretty stupid of me!

Comment: Don't be so self-critical: it's hard to trust our "continuous" intuition!

Comment: Though the fact that it doesn't work for general $\mathbb{Q}_p$ should make us suspicious of any pure continuity argument for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As regards the new question, if there's a counterexample $f$ for $n=2$, there's a counterexample for any $n$, as you can just take $f(f(x,y),z)$ when $n=3$, etc.  So if we expect there is a counterexample for $n=2$ then we shouldn't be able to prove this at all; I guess considering $n>2$ might still be helpful if that makes finding counterexamples easier?

Comment: @Harry, on the other hand, if there is an injective example in $ n \geq 3$ variables, by setting $n-2$ of them to $0$ we get an injective example in dimension $2.$ So you have shown that there is an injective polynomial in dimension 2 if and only if there is an example for every $n \geq 2.$    

Comment: Harry and Will, thank you for these comments. So, the problem is reduced to finding just one counter example for some $n>1$. (On the other hand, I guess that your comments have resulted in somebody's downvote.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-5x/4$. Then for $x\neq y$, $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $x^2+xy+y^2=5/4$ or $(2x+y)^2+3y^2=5$. The last equation clealy have real solutions. But if there are rational solutions, then there are integers $X,Y,N$ such that $(2X+Y)^2+3Y^2=5N^2$. This shows $X,Y,N$ all divisible by $5$, ...

Comment: This is a very nice counter example for $n=1$!

Comment: I'm surprised this was possible with just a cubic.

Comment: Also, this solution can be quickly tweaked to have integer coefficients; if there are no rational solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2=5/4$, then there can't be any to $x^2+xy+y^2=5$, either.  Hence $x^3-5x$ also works.

Comment: $x^3-2x$ also works.

Comment: Hailong, I used your solution as the hardest problem in my number theory class (to show that your $f(x)$ is injective). Two students (of 16) could do it.

Comment: @Wadim: (-: That's a good use of MO.  