# Polynomial bijection from ZxZ to Z?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is known that the polynomial $f(n,m)=\frac{1}{2}(n+m)(n+m+1)+m$ defines bijection
$\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ (Put pairs of $\mathbb{N}$ into the semi-infinite matrix and count them by diagonals). Does there exist a polynomial bijection 
$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$? The question is related to the open question 
about polynomial bijection $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-qxq-to-q).

Comment: Related but not decisive: http://www.thehcmr.org/issue1_2/bert_and_ernie.pdf

Comment: [It's also AMM 6028, which remains unsolved as far as I know.]

Comment: @Dickman: It took a me a while to know what you were talking about. Let me add the link http://books.google.es/books?id=KX6D6hefyA0C&pg=217

Comment: @Dicman and @Boumol: Thank you for interesting references. 
Interesting, AMM6028 asks for polynomials with integer coefficients. In fact, the bijection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ I know has rational coefficients. Does there exist polynomial $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ bijection with integer coefficients?

Comment: The "Bert and Ernie" link no longer works.

Comment: Updated: http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Favorite-Problem_A07_HCMR.pdf

Comment: To guard against further link rot: the article linked in Benjamin Dickman’s and Steve D’s comments above is *[My favourite problem: Bert and Ernie](http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Favorite-Problem_A07_HCMR.pdf)*, by Zachary Abel, in the Harvard College Mathematical Review, Fall 2007; and the AMM 6028 mentioned by Benjamin Dickman and linked by boumol is to the problem of that number by F. David Hammer from the American Mathematical Monthly, not sure exactly what date/issue, also in the Index of Mathematical Problems, 1975–79, p.217.

Answer (score 10):

It is an open problem. Maximal results about bijections from
$\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$  to $\mathbb N$ are contained in

> John S. Lew, Arnold L. Rosenberg,
>   *Polynomial indexing of integer lattice-points I. General concepts and quadratic polynomials*, J. Number Theory **10** (1978) pp 192-214, doi:[10.1016/0022-314X(78)90035-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X%2878%2990035-5).
>   *Polynomial indexing of integer lattice-points II. Nonexistence results for higher-degree polynomials*, J. Number Theory **10** (1978) pp 215-243,
>   doi:[10.1016/0022-314X(78)90036-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X%2878%2990036-7)

Comment: I edited the references and links.