# Cubic function $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be injective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials

It is easy to show, with an explicit construction, that a *homogeneous* cubic function $f: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is not injective. I am seeking a proof of the same result without the condition that $f$ is homogeneous.

For a homogeneous cubic:

$$f(x,y)=a x^3+b x^2 y+c x y^2+d y^3$$

if we take a generic point $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$, the tangent to the curve:

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=0$$

will intersect the curve at a second point, $(x_1, y_1)$, with rational coordinates. To see this, note that we can parameterise the tangent line as:

$$L(\lambda) = (x_0,y_0) + \lambda\space (\partial_y f(x,y), -\partial_x f(x,y))|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}$$

Then the cubic in $\lambda$:

$$F(\lambda) = f(L(\lambda)) - f(x_0,y_0)$$

will have rational coefficients and a double root at $\lambda=0$, so its third root $\lambda_3$ must be real and rational.  So:

$$(x_1,y_1) = L(\lambda_3)$$

will have rational coordinates, and will satisfy:

$$f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_0,y_0)$$

If we choose any integer $D$ such that:

$$(x_2,y_2) = D \space (x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\
(x_3,y_3) = D \space (x_1,y_1) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$$

we can exploit the homogeneity of $f$ to obtain:

$$f(x_2,y_2) = D^3 f(x_0,y_0) = D^3 f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_3,y_3)$$

If $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, we can write explicit formulas for $x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3$ as 7th degree homogeneous polynomials in $x_0,y_0,a,b,c,d$.

My question is: when $f$ is **not** homogeneous, can we construct explicit pairs of distinct points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that demonstrate $f$ is not injective?

For a *quadratic* in two variables with rational coefficients, there is a very simple choice of distinct integer points that demonstrate non-injectivity. Given:

$$q(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f$$

then

$$q(\alpha\space (-e,d)) = q(\alpha\space (e,-d))$$

and for rational $d,e$ we can choose $\alpha$ to make these points integers.  If $d=e=0$ we can use any pair of integers $(x,y)$ and their opposite.

Note that the points we have constructed for the homogeneous case do not cover *all* pairs with repeated values.  The plot shows an example of two points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the same value for a homogeneous cubic that do not lie on a tangent to the level curve. Pairs like these can be found easily enough by a brute force computation, and they will typically have much smaller coordinates than those found via tangent lines, but I am not aware of any method to construct them directly.

[image: Plot of -14x^3-23x^2 y+5x y^2+y^3=-11]

Comment: By contrast, the quartic $(3x^2+x+1)+(3x^2+x+1+3y^2+y+1)^2$ is injective on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. This comes from 10.3 at http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Favorite-Problem_A07_HCMR.pdf, as linked in the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138106/are-surjectivity-and-injectivity-of-polynomial-functions-from-mathbbqn-to