# A special oscillatory orbit in space

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, singularity-theory, counterexamples, real-analytic-structures

**Edit:** According to the comment of Prof. Eremenko I revise the question.

19 years ago, I have heard the following problem from a specialist of dynamical system. During these 19 years, I was in contact with him and I asked him if there is a solution to this problem He always answered me "No, I did not find any answer yet". Now I quote the problem here:

**Problem:**

> Is there a real analytic vector field locally defined around origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has an isolated singularity at origin and satisfies the following:
>
> **There exist an orbit $\gamma(t)$ which tends to origin as $t$ goes to $+\infty$ and the closure of$\{ \frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|},\;t\in\mathbb{R}^+\}$ has a nonempty interior in $S^2$**

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. The image of a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb R^+$ has $\sigma$-finite Hausdorff $1$-dimensional measure, and therefore has $2$-dimensional measure $0$.
In fact, $C^1$ can even be weakened to differentiable: see my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May be I miss remember the precise formulation of his problem.

Comment: He probably means that the limit set of $\gamma(t)/|\gamma(t)|$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes yes yes that is the true formulation. I revise the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Robert  I revise the question.