# Explicit transitive flow on disc

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, flows

$D_n\triangleq \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \|x\|\leq 1\right\}$ with its subspace topology.  By a transitive flow on $D_n$ I mean a continuous function
$$
\phi: [0,1]\times D_n\rightarrow D_n,
$$
which is continuously differentiable in its first argument, such that the set
$$
\left\{
\phi(t,x): t\in [0,1]
\right\}
$$
is dense in $D_n$ for some $x \in D_n$.

Are there explicit examples, in closed-form, for such a function $\phi$?

**Note:**
If we only require $\phi$ to be continuous, then the [Hahn–Mazurkiewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) guarantees the existence of such a surjective continuous function:
$$
\psi:[0,1]\rightarrow D_n.
$$
Taking $\phi(t,x)\triangleq \psi(t)$ gives the existence of a *continuous* such function.  However, this result doesn't guarantee that $\phi$ is smooth or give a closed-form expression in this case...

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking for a $D_n$-filling path, by shrinking $\phi(t,D_n)$ to $\phi(t,x)$?

Comment: (and by compactness one doesn't exist?)

Comment: Indeed one exists by Hahn-Mazurkiewicz (I added details above) but I'm looking some something a bit more explicit (and only on a dense subset of $D_n$ really...)

Comment: Sorry, I misread that as open disk. Obviously one exists on the closed one.

Comment: Ok, based on edit history it was an open disk when I sent my comment.

Comment: Actually, I only noticed the typo following your comment (so actually thanks).

Comment: It was in parentheses because I figured it was indeed a typo, but my cellphone screen is so broken that I refigured I just misread it on the go. Also, doesn't https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists answer your question?

Comment: (The image is compact so dense image is the same as surjective.)

Comment: You can find tons of explicit space-filling curve constructions by a search. If you want something that "looks like a formula", see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921985/what-is-the-hilbert-curves-equation . (Any answer to your question with $n \geq 2$ will also give a space-filling path on $[0,1]^2$ so it seems to me that this question is a duplicate. I mean the continuous part, after ruling out smooth ones.)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "continuous differentiable" that for any fixed $x$, the function $t \mapsto \partial_t \phi(t,x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then the image (for the same fixed $x$) of $\{\phi(t,x), t\}$ must have finite length, since $|\partial_t \phi(t,x)|$ is continuous on a closed interval and hence bounded.

But if this image is dense in $D_n$ for $n \geq 2$, it must have infinite length, a contradiction.

---

Proof of the latter statement: there exists a constant $c_n$ such that for every positive integer $K$, $D_n$ contains a subset $S_K$ containing $K^n$ points such that the pairwise distance between the points are at least $c_n / K$. (Just take a rectangular grid.) Therefore any space-filling curve must have length at least $c_n K^{n-1}$. Take $K\to \infty$.