# Again, polynomial bijection $f:{\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\to {\mathbb Q}$

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

Assume that there is no [polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21003/147204) $f(x,y)\in{\mathbb Q}[x,y]{}$ such that $f\colon {\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\to {\mathbb Q}$ is a bjiection. Does this imply that there is no polynomial $f(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb Q}[x,y,z]{}$ such that $f:{\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}\to {\mathbb Q}$ is a bijection ?

Comment: What do you think about it? Show please your attempts.

Comment: Why "Again" in the title? Was this question already asked before?

Comment: @Wowoju https://mathoverflow.net/q/21003/17064 (OP should have linked this)

Comment: Trivial, but worth noting that the converse holds: $\mathbb{Q}^2\leftrightarrow \mathbb{Q} \implies \mathbb{Q}^2\times\mathbb{Q}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. What is the presumption? Maybe OP has no fruitful attempts or promising ideas to show - that wouldn't invalidate the question. A trivial answer would, but is there one?

Comment: I doubt there is a simple "formal" argument for this. In various categories (e.g. groups) it is possible to have an object $A$ isomorphic to $A^3$ but not isomorphic to $A^2$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Is there a natural category whose isomorphisms are the polynomial bijections?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I doubt it (and I didn't mean to imply that). If there is, it definitely cannot have the obvious concretization, because the inverse of $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto x^3$ is not a polynomial bijection.

Comment: Maybe you can localise the category of polynomial maps at the maps that induce bijections...

Comment: Can anyone extend Bresciani's conditional results on $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ to answer this question? https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.01090

Comment: @MattF. If you assume the geometric Lang conjecture in addition to the weak Bombieri-Lang conjecture, then my result rules out the case in which the generic fiber is of general type. It remains then to address the cases in which the fiber has lower Kodaira dimension, but that's probably easy.

Comment: Actually, if one uses more generally the methods of my paper rather than the result as stated, the geometric Lang conjecture can be avoided.