# Is the two variable fragment of arithmetic, i.e., theory of ($\mathbb{N}, + ,\times$), decidable?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, peano-arithmetic, decidability

Any references would be appreciated. Most places only address different vocabularies (e.g. a survey of arithmetical definability by Bes).

Comment: In "two-variable arithmetic" does every sentence have an equivalent prenex form consisting of an $x$-quantifier and a $y$-quantifier (in some order) followed by an open formula?

Comment: No. In the first place, there are only finitely many formulae of the type you are talking about because the open formula can only say how x and y stand in relation to each other and the vocabulary is finite.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked "Is every sentence equivalent to a boolean combination of 2-quantifier formulas in prenex form?" Also, It would be helpful if you said what you mean by "the two variable fragment of arithmetic".

Comment: @ThinniyamSrinivasanRamanatha That's true in a relational language, but not one with function symbols. There are infinitely many non-equivalent quantifier-free ("open") formulas, e.g. $x = y$, $x + x = y$, $x+x+x = y$, etc.

Comment: @SJR Usually in the "two variable fragment", one is able to rebind variables. For example $\forall x\, \exists y\, (\varphi(x,y) \land (\forall x\, \psi(x,y)))$. Relevant terms to search for are "finite variable logic" and "pebble games".

Comment: @AlexKruckman My bad. But I believe one should be able to show that there are predicates definable which require you to nest and rebind variables.

Comment: If we just look at sentences with two quantifiers, without allowing variables to be rebound, then the answer is positive in practice, and conjectured to be always positive -- see the answer and comment of @FelipeVoloch at https://mathoverflow.net/a/21503/44143