# What polynomials biject from $\mathbb{N}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

Perhaps there are none with integral coefficients; so let us admit rational coefficients. The map $(x, y) \mapsto x + \frac{1}{2}(x + y)(x + y + 1)$ is well known, and swapping $x$ and $y$ in the formula yields another, so we have two for starters.

Comment: There have been a number of questions related to this, including one of the highest-voted ones by Bjorn Poonen. You might search through existing questions.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9731/polynomial-representing-all-nonnegative-integers and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-qxq-to-q

Comment: In particular, the first link tells us that this question is an open problem.

Comment: @Martin actually that is only asking about surjectivity when the domain is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, but I agree that it has some bearing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Describing such bijections is an open problem. Maximal result (there is no other bijections among polynomials of degree not higher than 4) are contained in

> John S. Lew, Arnold L. Rosenberg,
>   *Polynomial indexing of integer lattice-points I. General concepts and quadratic polynomials*, J. Number Theory **10** (1978) pp 192-214, doi:[10.1016/0022-314X(78)90035-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X%2878%2990035-5).
>   *Polynomial indexing of integer lattice-points II. Nonexistence results for higher-degree polynomials*, J. Number Theory **10** (1978) pp 215-243,
>   doi:[10.1016/0022-314X(78)90036-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X%2878%2990036-7)

Comment: What, exactly, are you claiming to be an open problem? As far as I can see, the question asks for a list of examples.

Comment: Ok, Describing such bijections is an open problem.