# Is the number of representations as the sum of two elements of a polynomial sequence always small?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a degree $d>1$ polynomial with integer coefficients. Define

$$r(n) := | \{x,y \in \mathbb{Z} : f(x)+f(y) = n  \}|. $$

My question is:

> > Is it true that $r(n) \ll_{\epsilon} n^{\epsilon} $ for $\epsilon >0$?

In certain cases (such as $ f(x)=x^{2k}$), one can "factor" the problem and deduce the desired result from the divisor bound. However, I do not see how to approach the general case in this manner. I am aware that there is a weaker but more general result of [Bombieri and Pila](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077308005) which states that

$$r'(n,M) := | \{x,y \in \mathbb{Z} : f(x,y) = n, |x|,|y| < M  \}| $$

satisfies $r'(n,M) \ll_{\epsilon} M^{1/d + \epsilon} $when $f(x,y)$ is an absolutely irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. In this greater level of generality this is nearly best possible as can be seen by taking $f(x,y) = x^d -y$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a story (similar to classical theta functions, along the lines of Fourier coefficient of modular forms) for series of the shape $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \exp(2\pi i f(n)x)$ where $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a degree $d > 2$ polynomial?

Comment: A related question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45511.

Comment: The implied constant in the bound you seek can depend on $f$, correct?

Comment: @Bobby, yes the constant can depend on $f$.

Comment: I would even think that $r(n)$ is bounded when $d$ is at least five.

Comment: @GH, are you saying that because then the genus is at least 2, and boundedness would follow from the Bombieri-Lang Conjecture, or is there something more concrete that would apply to these specific curves?

Comment: I'm curious if an improvement on the divisor bound is known for, say, $f(x)=x^5$?

Comment: I assume Bobby Grizzard is referring to the result of Caporaso-Harris-Mazur that shows that Bombieri-Lang gives a uniform bound on the rational points of any curve of a fixed genus greater than or equal to 2: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1325796 .  This would indeed seem to give GH's claim, conditional of course on Bombieri-Lang.

Comment: @TerryTao correct.  I should have said more.  And I suppose the uniform boundedness conjecture about curves of fixed genus $g \geq 2$ is a famous enough conjecture that I should have said it would follow from that, but I don't know I nice name for that conjecture.

Comment: Worth pointing out?: using the main theorem of Gaël Rémond's 2011 paper "Borne polynomiale pour le nombre de points rationnels des courbes" http://jtnb.cedram.org/item?id=JTNB_2011__23_1_251_0
gives that the number of *rational* points on the curve is at most $n^{2^{3^{D^2}}},$ where $D$ is the degree of $f$, again once the degree is large enough to make the genus $\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to comment so I will just mention something here, though I would guess you might have recognized it already.

You can certainly bound the number of solutions to $f(x)-f(y)=n$ by writing $$f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)H(x,y)$$ for some polynomial $H$ that depends only on $f$. Then $x-y=d$ divides $n$ and $H(x,x-d)=n/d$ so there are $O_f(1)$ choices for $x$. Going from differences to sums is probably hard.

Comment: I had also observed this after posting the question. It certainly seems that this can't be generalized in any straightforward way to sums since there are polynomials such that f(x)+f(y) does not have linear factors.

Comment: Do you know when $f(x)+f(y)$ is absolutely irreducible? It's tempting to try and repeat the argument in a number field.

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought about that briefly but didn't get too far. This quickly leads to questions outside of my expertise.

Comment: The answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105304/criteria-for-irreducibility-of-polynomial/105323#105323 seems relevant here.